# Rails intersect query with joint table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3.2 app, there is an `AttendedUniversity` model with the following fields:

```
university_name
major_name
university_type # 0 for undergrad and 1 for graduate
advisor_id # for the Advisor model
```

The `Advisor` model has many `attended_universities` and an `attended_university` belongs to an `advisor`.

I want to fetch advisors who had a certain undergrad and a certain graduate e.g. major1 for undergrad and major2 for graduate.

I've tried the following:

```
Advisor.includes(:attended_universities).
where("attended_universities.university_name = 'university1' AND
       attended_universities.major_name = 'major1' AND
       attended_universities.university_type = 0").
where("attended_universities.university_name = 'university2' AND
       attended_universities.major_name = 'major2' AND
       attended_universities.university_type = 1")
```

The above is giving me the empty results when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're matching with your query is that each university in the row should have the name `'university1'` AND the name `'university2'`.

Similar checks are being performed for other conditions. Since no one university row in your table will have two names, two majors, or two types, you will be served with 0 results.

This is going to be a bit more complicated then you might have initially thought, if you want to do it the optimized way.

You would need to join the universities table twice to your advisors table and then apply the conditions separately to each joined table. The following should work:

```
joins_str = ->(tn) do
  "INNER JOIN attended_universities AS #{tn} ON #{tn}.advisor_id = advisors.id"
end

criteria_one = {name: 'university1',
                major_name: 'major1',
                university_type: 0}

criteria_two = {name: 'university2',
                major_name: 'major2',
                university_type: 1}

Advisor.
joins(joins_str.call('au_one')).
joins(joins_str.call('au_two')).
where(au_one: criteria_one).
where(au_two: criteria_two).
group("advisors.id")
```

I would go with the top method.

You could also do it the unoptimized way, perhaps making the code a bit more readable:

```
advisors_with_unis = Advisor.joins(:attended_universities)

# fetch advisor ids that fulfill criteria_one
ids_one = advisors_with_unis.
          where(attended_universities: criteria_one).
          pluck("DISTINCT advisors.id")

# fetch advisor ids that fulfill criteria_two
ids_two = advisors_with_unis.
          where(attended_universities: criteria_two).
          pluck("DISTINCT advisors.id")

# get intersection of both id arrays
ids = ids_one & ids_two

# get advisors
Advisor.where(id: ids)
```

Yet another solution would be to fetch all records from the DB and then use Ruby for filtering:

```
def university_matches?(uni, name, major, uni_type)
  uni.name == name &&
  uni.major_name == major &&
  uni.university_type == uni_type
end

Advisor.includes(:attended_universities).select do |advisor|
  universities = advisor.attended_universities

  universities.any? do |uni|
    university_matches?(uni, 'university1', 'major1', 0)
  end &&

  universities.any? do |uni|
    university_matches?(uni, 'university2', 'major2', 1)
  end
end
```

As mentioned before, I'd go with the first one.